# Xamarin forms cannot access controls by it "x:Name"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Today i faced some issue. Please help me.

I created a cross platform application on IOS and Android. So i trying to access my MainPage controls form .cs file but i can't. Here is provided code.

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Movies"
             x:Class="Movies.MainPage">


    <TableView x:Name="mainTable">
        <TableSection>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Label Text="Hello"></Label>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </TableSection>
    </TableView>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace Movies
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mainTable.
        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XZS1.png

Project runs successfully.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGMwW.png

I tried rebuild and even restore VS17 in VS installer.
this.mainTable doesn't work either.

Comment: Does it work this.mainTable ?

Comment: No it isn't. I tried rebuild and even restore VS17 in VS installer

Comment: But code compiles? If you write Console.WriteLine(mainTable.ToString()); it will compile and write something?

Comment: It is compile with Console.WriteLine(mainTable.ToString());. Strange. "Xamarin.Forms.TableView" is output

Comment: It is compiling and i can use this controls, thanks but for me as beginner in Xamarin forms development it is really difficult to do it without  IntelliSense. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the .XAML file, select Properties.

See a Property called Custom Tool. Change its value from MSBuild:Compile to MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml or if it is blank set it to MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml.

This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Build the project once,then you can access the name in .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to build the solution first, then delete the hidden .vs folder in the root of folder of your project, then re-open.